# Datepicker disable previous 20 year from current year

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used date picker script.

I want to disable last 20 year from current year but dont know how to disable that?

I want validation for user Date of birth date picker ,user can not select date of birth from previous 20 year, but don't know how to privilege user to select date of birth from not previous 20 year .

can any one help me?

Comment: did you tried using minDate maxDate? In you case simply put maxDate as presentYear - 20

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#DOB").datepicker({

                    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                    startDate: '-100y',
                    endDate:'-20y'
 });
```

you can also use yearRange as:

```
$("#DOB").datepicker({

                    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                    yearRange: "-100:-20"
 });
```

Comment: Sorry, it will not work ,it will not disable last 20 year

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Datepicker option *[beforeShowDay](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay)* to disable the date according to the year:

```
$('.selector').datepicker({
  beforeShowDay: function (date) {
    var year = date.getFullYear()
    var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear()
    return [ year >= currentYear || year <= currentYear - 20 ]
  }
});
```